# How to prevent memory leak on allocation failure with consecutive uses of 'new'

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm implementing a C-API with C++ and at the interface I have to convert C++ like data structures to existing data structures of the C-API.

I am responsible for the memory of the data structure, so I can use new and delete, but from my understanding the following C++11 code can have a memory leak (this is just a dumbed down example):

```
#include <string>
#include <new>

struct container {
    char *message;
};

/* converts an std::string to a C data structure */
container *create_container(const std::string& message) {
    container *c = nullptr;
    try {
        container *c = new container;
        c->message = new char[message.length() + 1];
        message.copy(c->message, message.length());
        c->message[message.length()] = '\0';
    } catch (std::bad_alloc exception) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return c;
}

void destroy_container(container *c) {
    if (c != nullptr) {
        if (c->message != nullptr) {
            delete[] c->message;
        }
        delete c;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    container *c = create_container("message");
    destroy_container(c);

    return 0;
}
```

It would leak `c` if allocation of `c->message` fails.

So my question: How should I ideally deal with this situation?

What I came up with so far:

```
    /* ... */
    } catch (std::bad_alloc exception) {
        if (c != nullptr) {
            delete c;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
    /* ... */
```

Is there a better way to do this in C++?

This problem can also happen in C++ only applications if memory is managed with `new` and `delete` and you happen to use `new` twice in the same `try` block that catches `std::bad_alloc`.

Could this maybe be solved using smart pointers or some other way?

Comment: `auto c = std::make_unique<container>(); ... ; return c.release();` Now `container` will be freed automatically in case of abnormal return.

Comment: "Is there a better way to do this in C++?"  Use a std::string, not an array of char.

Comment: @NeilButterworth In this setup, `container` is a C-style data structure to be passed to C API. The whole point of the exercise is to translate between C++ classes and C PODs on the boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am responsible for the memory of the data structure
>
> How to prevent memory leak

The solution is to make somebody else responsible :) That might sound snide, but I find it insightful.

Put the memory management code inside a RAII container whose single responsibility is to release the memory when out of scope. Since C++11, that is RAII container can be implemented without overhead, and is already implemented for you in the standard library: `std::unique_ptr`.

As long as the memory is held by that unique pointer, if the unique pointer goes out of scope due to exception or otherwise, the memory will be freed. The underlying bare pointer can be released from the unique pointer and returned once all code that may throw has executed successfully.

---

> This problem can also happen in C++ only applications

The RAII container is even better in C++ where you keep the container for the entire lifetime of the object instead of releasing the memory into the wild.

---

PS.

```
if (c->message != nullptr) {
    delete[] c->message;
}
```

The test is completely redundant and this can be simplified to just

```
delete[] c->message;
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes my code much cleaner and easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

Store all pointers in `unique_ptr`.  Create with `make_unique` if C++14 or better ideally (may need 17 for arrays with make unique).

After allocating everything and checking, `.release` the unique pointers.